# Python doesn't want to import an App class(tkinter)

Tags: python, class, tkinter, attributeerror

I am working on a little programme that will serve as a chemistry calculator or sth like that, and I've run into some trouble along the way...

In the main file, I'm trying to import class Aplikacija from file grafika.py, but it doesn't seem to be working no matter how hard I try - I get the AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Aplikacija'.

It might be this is a beginner's problem, but I've been staring at the screen for a couple of hours and I have no clue as to what might be wrong. I'd be really grateful if you could help me out :)

P.S: please don't mind the variable's names as my native language isn't English...

The (shortened) code of the main file:

```
import grafika
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('ChemHelp v0.1')
root.minsize(360, 240)
#root.iconbitmap('mojaikona.ico')

p = grafika.Aplikacija(root)

root.mainloop()
```

And this is the whole grafika.py file (it's quite long...)

```
from Tkinter import *
import webbrowser

class Aplikacija():

    def __init__(self, master):

        #meni
        self.meni = Menu(master)
        master.config(menu=self.meni)
        self.meni.add_command(label="Periodni sistem", command=self.ps_okno)

        self.help_meni = Menu(self.meni)
        self.meni.add_cascade(label="Pomoč", menu=self.help_meni)
        self.help_meni.add_command(label="PDF", command=self.open_pdf)
        self.help_meni.add_command(label="Spletna dokumentacija", command=self.open_web)

        self.meni.add_command(label="O programu", command=self.open_about)
        self.meni.add_command(label="Zahvale", command=self.open_thanks)
        self.meni.add_command(label="Zapri", command=quit)

        #glavno okno
        body = Frame(root, width=360, height=240)
        body.pack()

        #izracun molske mase
        self.okno_masa = LabelFrame(body, text="Molska masa", padx=5, pady=5)
        self.okno_masa.grid(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.prompt1 = Label(self.okno_masa, text="Formula spojine: ")
        self.prompt1.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
        self.formula1 = Entry(self.okno_masa)
        self.formula1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.send1 = Button(self.okno_masa, text="Pošlji", command=lambda: self.gfx_molska_masa(self.okno_masa))
        self.send1.grid(row=1, columnspan=2)

        #izracun mnozine
        self.okno_mn = LabelFrame(body, text="Množina", padx=5, pady=5)
        self.okno_mn.grid(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.prompt2 = Label(self.okno_mn, text="Formula spojine: ")
        self.prompt2.grid(row=4, sticky=W)
        self.formula2 = Entry(self.okno_mn)
        self.formula2.grid(row=4, column=1)
        self.prompt3 = Label(self.okno_mn, text="Masa spojine: ")
        self.prompt3.grid(row=5, sticky=W)
        self.masa = Entry(self.okno_mn)
        self.masa.grid(row=5, column=1)
        self.send2 = Button(self.okno_mn, text="Pošlji", command=lambda: self.gfx_mnozina(self.okno_mn))
        self.send2.grid(row=6, columnspan=2)

    #funkcije
    def ps_okno(self):
        self.ps = Toplevel()
        self.ps.title("Periodni sistem")
        self.ps.minsize(480, 180)
        self.tekst = Label(self.ps, text="Tukaj bo periodni...")
        self.tekst.grid()
        self.zapri = Button(self.ps, text="Zapri", command=self.ps.destroy)
        self.zapri.grid()
        print("Okno odprto :P")

    def open_pdf(self):
        print("PDF odprt ;)")

    def open_web(self):
        self.url = 'http://test.org'
        webbrowser.open_new(self.url)
        print("Splet prečekiran :D")

    def open_about(self):
        self.o = Toplevel()
        self.o.title("O programu")
        self.o.minsize(300, 300)
        self.about = LabelFrame(self.o, text="O programu", padx=5, pady=5)
        self.about.grid(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.slika = PhotoImage(file="about_slika.gif")
        self.photo = Label(self.about, image=self.slika)
        self.photo.slika=self.slika
        self.photo.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
        self.avtor = Label(self.about, text="Avtor: ")
        self.avtor.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
        self.avtor2 = Label(self.about, text="Jane Doe")
        self.avtor2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.verzija = Label(self.about, text="Verzija programa: ")
        self.verzija.grid(row=2, sticky=W)
        self.verzija2 = Label(self.about, text="1.0")
        self.verzija2.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.jezik = Label(self.about, text="Pisano v programskem jeziku Python. © 2013")
        self.jezik.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)
        self.zapri = Button(self.about, text="Zapri", command=self.o.destroy)
        self.zapri.grid(row=4, columnspan=2)
        print("Kdo bo to sploh bral? :O")

    def open_thanks(self):
        self.h = Toplevel()
        self.h.title("Zahvale")
        self.h.minsize(200, 200)
        self.zahvale = LabelFrame(self.h, text="Zahvale", width=100, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.zahvale.grid(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.z_vsebina = Label(self.zahvale, text="Rada bi se zahvalila bla bla... in tle pol ful teksta al neki...")
        self.z_vsebina.grid()
        self.mentor = LabelFrame(self.h, text="Mentor", width=100, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.mentor.grid(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.m_vsebina = Label(self.mentor, text="John Does, prof.")
        self.m_vsebina.grid()
        self.viri = LabelFrame(self.h, text="Viri", width=100, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.viri.grid(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.v_vsebina = Label(self.viri, text="http://test.org \nhttp://www.test.com")
        self.v_vsebina.grid()
        self.zapri = Button(self.h, text="Zapri", command=self.h.destroy)
        self.zapri.grid()
        print("Tale stvar je lame -.-")

    def gfx_molska_masa(self, frame):
        self.rezultat = Entry(frame)
        self.rezultat.config(width="9")
        self.rezultat.grid(row=3)
        self.molska_masa = "187"
        self.rezultat.insert(0, self.molska_masa)
        self.enota = Label(frame, text="g/mol")
        self.enota.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
        print("Molska masa je")

    def gfx_mnozina(self, frame):
        self.rezultat = Entry(frame)
        self.rezultat.config(width="8")
        self.rezultat.grid(row=7)
        self.mnozina = "1.0"
        self.rezultat.insert(0, self.mnozina)
        self.enota = Label(frame, text="mol")
        self.enota.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=W)
        print("Mnozina je")
```

When I run the code from the main file in the grafika.py file, it works fine, no errors or anything...

Comment: Stick a `print(grafika.__file__)` right after `import graficka` in the main file. Does it refer to the right file? If it is pointing at a `.pyc` file, delete it so it is forced to read the `.py` file again.

Comment: Tried that, but it points to the .py file, not the .pyc... Thanks for taking your time anyways ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already imported the file once, another import won't reload it - modules are cached. You need to `reload(grafika)` to pick up your latest changes.

Comment: Thank you, this worked like a charm :) So everytime I make any changes in the module, I have to reload it before it catches up to the newest change? Sorry for asking silly questions and thank you for your swift response :)

Comment: @Emayla, yes you need to `reload` every time you make (and save) a change. Or you can shut down Python and start it up again, but `reload` is usually easier. There are cases where it doesn't work properly, but I don't know what they are and have never run into one.